# Android - how to generate GreenDao Entities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, greendao

I'm handling an Android Project my company started last year.
I got a GreenDaoGenerator project with the infamous custom ExampleDaoGenerator.java. I'm pretty sure this is all well configured in order to work well and generate my entities.

I started developing the Android Project (which is in another folder/package, of course) but now I need to change the way Entities are instantiated in it.

I have a good amount of classes with the

```
// THIS CODE IS GENERATED BY greenDAO, DO NOT EDIT. Enable "keep" sections if you want to edit.
```

on the top of them and I'd like to re-generate them since I commented out some rows in my custom ExampleDaoGenerator.

How can I do that? GreenDaoGenerator is not an Android Studio project, doesn't have any build.gradle file. It doesn't have any .class file either, just the java file and libraries to load for DaoGeneration. I didn't find anywhere in GreenDao documentation how to run the proper generation and harvest the created classes.

I tried of course `javac the.full.path/src/whatever/ExampleDaoGenerator.java` but it didn't work :-(

Do you happen to see what I'm doing wrong? I expected Android Studio Project to re-generate the database whenever the signatures are changed but it seems like it does not.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a **Java library** module (*File > New > New module..*) to your Android project (assuming you're using *Android Studio*), and insert the generation code inside `public static void main(String[] args) {}` in this module's `.java` class. Then *Run* it and the code will be generated in you main app's module.

See how I did it in my [blog post](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/tutorial-how-to-integrate-greendao/).

Comment: Thank you. I had already figured it out myself but I forgot to self-answer this question.

Comment: Oh that's the part I forgot, you have to run it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

mmm.... manually? backup previous created classes (model), run the generator again and compare-update data?

I don't know if there are any new doc [here](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/how-to-get-started/), but allways is a good reading place. [get project](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO) also available.

Good luck!